# View Model class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to make a view model class in Django whose main purpose is only to display data in templates. like I have an auction model which has the following properties:

```
class Auction(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4000)
    edit_token = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    starting_price = models.DecimalField(max_length=30, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2)
    bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_length=30, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    winner_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=STATUS__CHOICES, default='Active')
    revision = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Now I only want to show title, description, starting_price etc to view and main purpose of the view model is I want to change the value of starting_price based on user currency selection so I wanted to add some business logic during the transformation of Database Model class to Template Model class.

Can I use form models or are there any other models I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in different ways, 
You can use HTML forms, then tie with model. You can refer this youtube link for a small understanding

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huk9tIRD_rQ&list=PLsyeobzWxl7r2ukVgTqIQcl-1T0C2mzau&index=14&t=0s

or you can use `model form`

```
class AuctionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=4000)
    starting_price = forms.DecimalField(
        decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)



    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ['title', 'description', 'starting_price']
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am asking, the only way is to use a form model or is there any other thing I can use in this?

Comment: You can use HTML forms also, then tie with model. You can refer this youtube link for a small understanding 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huk9tIRD_rQ&list=PLsyeobzWxl7r2ukVgTqIQcl-1T0C2mzau&index=14&t=0s'

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this thing thanks :)  can you edit your answer so I can mark as correct